# Нет вывода alert. В чем проблема?

Tags: javascript

Вот мой код:

```js
while (true) {
let x = +prompt("Введите число:", '');
  if (!x) break;
  else if (x <= 100)
      alert("Неправильно! Введите число более 100:");
else if (x > 100) {
            break;
            alert("Вы правы!");}
}
```

Проблема в сочетании с директивой break?

Также вопрос такой: Почему при изменении места строки, которая объявляет переменную, код работает по-другому? Он больше не выводит бесконечное количество раз поле ввода, а бесконечно выводит "Неправильно!..." Что именно происходит в момент изменения порядка строк?

```js
let x = +prompt("Введите число:", ''); //переставили наверх
while (true) {
      if (!x) break;
      else if (x <= 100)
          alert("Неправильно! Введите число более 100:");
    else if (x > 100) {
                break;
                alert("Вы правы!");}
    }
```

Comment: Вы что-нибудь знаете про циклы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прочтите более внимательнее о [`break` и `continue`](https://learn.javascript.ru/while-for#metki-dlya-break-continue)

```js
while (true) {
  let x = +prompt("Введите число:", '');
  if(!x) break;
  else if(x <= 100)
    alert("Неправильно! Введите число более 100:");
  else if(x > 100) {
    alert("Вы правы!");
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
else if (x > 100) {
  alert("Вы правы!");
  break;
}
```